# jQuery save and Load function

Tags: jquery, load

I have this code which saves the data contain vectorOutput and vectorName when the save button get clicked. Based on the save function I want to write a function which load this data when the button load get clicked. Can anybody help me?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){           
             /*if the submit Button gets clicked this function is called*/
            jQuery("#submitButton").click(function() {

                /*the text of the html field output and vectorName are stored into javascript variables vectorOutput & VectorName*/
                var vectorOutput = jQuery("#output").val();
                var vectorName = jQuery("#vectorName").val();

                /*the jQuery.ajax gets openend*/
                jQuery.ajax({
                    /*typ POST gets defined*/
                    type: "POST",
                    /*the PHP file that receives the POST*/
                    url: "parser22.php",
                    /*the data that gets transfered*/
                    data: {
                        /*vector: contains the geometric information of the overlay, in kml format*/
                        vector: vectorOutput,

                        /*name: contains the chosen name of the geofence*/
                        name: vectorName
                    },
                    success: function(html){ //so, if data is retrieved, store it in html
                        /*if the save button gets clicked the field with the geofencename */
                        jQuery("#output").val('');
                        /*and kml koordinates get emptied*/
                        jQuery("#vectorName").val('');
                        /*to show the user that it worked alert Window pops up*/
                        alert("Geofence successfully saved!");
                    }
                }); //close jQuery.ajax(
            });
        });
```

Comment: still stands the question, where do you want to load it from? This data has to be stored somewhere...

Comment: the config.php inside parser22.php is called which make the connection to database. <?php
//connect to the database
//mysql_connect
$db_conn=pg_pconnect("host='' port= dbname='' user='' password=''");
if (!$db_conn) {
    echo pg_last_error();
}

Comment: Sorry but since I am not that much familiar with programming I am somehow confused. Can you guide me or give me solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm giving you a guide, so you can learn :)

So, assuming the `parser22.php` file recieves the `POST` vars, and then does an `INSERT INTO` statement to you database...

Try to do the same, but instead use `GET` as the `type:` in your ajax call, and perform a `SELECT` statement on the database.

Use firebug (firefox) or developer tools (chrome) to see what is actually being send and received.

Use this in your `ajax()` call to do some logging:

```
success function(html): {console.log(htm)}, 
error function(e) {console.log(e)}
```

to get info in the console. console.log is a better alternative for `alert()`

**EDIT**

```
/*the SELECT query gets created*/ 
$eintrag = "SELECT geofencename,geometry,fk_user_geofence FROM public.geofence"; 

/*the above mentioned query gets executed 
  --> this always executes a query, no matter what kind */ 
$eintragen = pg_query($eintrag);
```

see also [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) for a small and simple introduction to SQL and querying databases

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful guidance.                         /*the query for the insert gets created*/     
 $eintrag = "INSERT INTO public.geofence (geofencename,geometry,fk_user_geofence) VALUES ('$name','$vector','$id')";
 
 /*the above mentioned query gets executed */
 $eintragen = pg_query($eintrag);                            these two lines of code are used in parse22.php to insert data to database. what should I write instead of these two lines of code?